# How to run a R for loop on data stored in data lake where there are multiple lines to a single row & column?

Tags: r

Sample illustration of the data in data lake looks like the following.

[image: data lake]

I have tried the following code but the output is skipping the 0th line value for every column and row.

```
Data_extract <- data[data$Row == '4', ]

Data_extract <- Data_extract[Data_extract$Line >= 0, ]

line_count <- length(Data_extract[, "Row"])

line_num <- 0

for (line in seq_len(line_count)) {

  col_suffix <- paste0("_", line_num)

  temp_col_A <- Data_extract[Data_extract$Column == "A" & 
   Data_extract$Row=='4'& Data_extract$Line == line,  
   ][match(EUR[,"REF.NO"], Data_extract[Data_extract$Column=="A" & 
   Data_extract$Row=='4'& Data_extract$Line == line, 'REF.NO']),  
   'Value']

  temp_col_B <- Data_extract[Data_extract$Column == "B" & 
   Data_extract$Row=='4'& Data_extract$Line == line,  
   ][match(EUR[,"REF.NO"], Data_extract[Data_extract$Column=="B" & 
   Data_extract$Row=='4'& Data_extract$Line == line, 'REF.NO']),  
   'Value']

  temp_col_C <- Data_extract[Data_extract$Column == "C" & 
   Data_extract$Row=='4'& Data_extract$Line == line, 
   ][match(EUR[,"REF.NO"], Data_extract[Data_extract$Column=="C" &  
   Data_extract$Row=='4'& Data_extract$Line == line, 'REF.NO']),  
   'Value']

  if (any(!is.na(temp_col_A)) || any(!is.na(temp_col_B)) ||  
    any(!is.na(temp_col_C)) || any(!is.na(temp_col_D))) {

    EUR[, paste0("Info1", col_suffix)] <- temp_col_A

    EUR[, paste0("Info2", col_suffix)] <- temp_col_B

    EUR[, paste0("Info3", col_suffix)] <- temp_col_C 

    line_num <- line_num + 1

  }

  if (line_num > line_count) {

    break

  }

}
```

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(data)` as part of your question instead of a screenshot of your data. Also, please provide what is your expected outcome. It's not clear from your question and from your code what you are looking to achieve.